# Regex to ignore empty paths or paths with certain strings and accept all others

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to iterate over 1000s of paths which look something like this (the indices are not part of the string, I just added them here to illustrate what I'm trying to do):

```
[ 0] /root/council/news/
[ 1] /root/council/news/latest-news
[ 2] /root/council/news/new-management-strategy-lagoon-entrance
[ 3] /root/council/news/be-inspired-curly-composters
[ 4] /root2/council/news/
[ 5] /root2/council/news/latest-news
[ 6] /root2/council/news/safety-repair-works-planned-cemetery
[ 7] /root2/council/news/learn-about-our-top-8-precious-bushland-plants
[ 8] /path/council/news/latest-news
[ 9] /path/council/news/safety-repair-works-planned-cemetery
[10] /path/council/news/learn-about-our-top-8-precious-bushland-plants
```

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will ignore an empty end path and a path that has `latest-news` as an example.

So in this example it should ignore paths; `0, 1, 4, 5, 8`, and I should end up with:

```
/root/council/news/new-management-strategy-lagoon-entrance
/root/council/news/be-inspired-curly-composters
/root2/council/news/safety-repair-works-planned-cemetery
/root2/council/news/learn-about-our-top-8-precious-bushland-plants
/path/council/news/safety-repair-works-planned-cemetery
/path/council/news/learn-about-our-top-8-precious-bushland-plants
```

**Update:**
Following @thethiny comment, this is what I have tried:

```
re.findall("(\/council\/news\/[a-zA-Z0-9])")
```

But this still catches `/latest-news`

I'll also add that `/latest-news` is just one of many ignore cases, which will be maintained by non-tech people.

NOTE: I'm using Python.

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Besides you didn't showcase any of the attempts you tried, just a reminder that Stack Overflow is to help you with problems you face, not to write code for you.

Comment: `if path.endswith("/news/") or path.endswith("/latest-news"): continue`

Comment: @thethiny, thanks for your comments,  I've updated my question to include a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your attempt and see what's wrong with it then proceed to propose a fix.
`(\/council\/news\/[a-zA-Z0-9])`
This tries to catch `/council/news/LETTERORDIGIT` Which is not what you want. You want it to catch the **resource** entirely, not only a single letter. So the first fix is to add a `+`, and you're not catching the `-` so we add that as well.

`(\/council\/news\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)`.

Now this is catching everything that has a resource after `/news/`. But you want it to ignore `latest-news` so we're going to add a negative **lookbehind** operator `?<!` that would stop at the end of the string (`$`). Our new regex becomes something like this: `\/council\/news\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?<!latest-news)$`

Now if you're using `findall` or `search` this would be sufficient, but if you're using `match` then you're gonna need to add some starting boundaries. Our final regex becomes `^.*\/council\/news\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?<!latest-news)$`, we have marked the start of the string `^` and any letters until `/council/news/` using `.*`.

Now we tidy it up a bit by making it case insensitive, removing unnecessary escapes, and changing the grouping, and finally adding an optional `/` at the end.

[`(?i)^.*/council/news/(\[\w\-\]+)(?<!latest-news)/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/6lZ7zB/1) where `(?i)` means case insensitive

Now we come to your most important part

> [sic] is just one of many ignore cases

And for that we end up with

```py
my_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?i)"
    r"^.*"
    r"/council/news/"
    r"([\w\-]+)"
    + "".join([r"(?<!" + path + r")" for path in ignored_paths]) +
    r"/?$"
)
```

Add your ignored paths to `ignored_paths` array and you're good to go.

Note that it is very very slow to do it using regex and it's much better to either:

- Implement the same using `.endswith()`
- Capture the resource, if it's empty you discard it, else if the resource is within a set.

For the 2nd case you're better off doing it this way:

```py
my_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?i)"
    r"^.*"
    r"/council/news/"
    r"([\w\-]+)"
    r"/?$"
)

ignore_set = {
    "latest-news",
    "oldest-news",
    "site-map",
}

for path in paths:
    find_re = my_pattern.search(path)
    if not find_re: continue
    resource = find_re.groups()[0].strip()
    if not resource: continue
    if resource in ignore_set: continue
    # At this point your resource is valid, so continue.
```